# web page dropdown animation jittering

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

So, I'm trying to make a dropdown animation for a list, that activates when hovered, and it mostly just works as I want it to. I used **GSAP** to make it work by first setting the height so only the title can be seen, then on hover increasing the height of the list, and at the same time moving it down the same amount, but no matter how much I try to adjust the values, there's still jittering, is there a way to do this properly with GSAP, or would I need to use something else?

```js
let languagesDropdown = document.querySelector(".languages-dropdown")
let languageList = document.querySelector(".language-list")

gsap.set(languagesDropdown, {
  y: -250
})

languagesDropdown.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  gsap.to(languagesDropdown, {
    ease: "power1.inOut",
    duration: 0.2,
    y: -92,
    maxHeight: "375px",
  });
});

languagesDropdown.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  gsap.to(languagesDropdown, {
    ease: "power1.inOut",
    duration: 0.2,
    y: -250,
    maxHeight: 59,
  });
});
```

```css
.languages-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 17px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(53, 53, 53);
  height: 375px;
  width: 230px;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.language-list {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 59px;
}

.language {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.5/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="languages-dropdown hidden">
  <p class="title">Języki programowania</p>
  <div class="language-list">
    <br>
    <a href="subpages/sub-page0.html" class="language">Javascript</a>
    <a href="subpages/sub-page1.html" class="language">B</a>
    <a href="subpages/sub-page2.html" class="language">C</a>
    <a href="subpages/sub-page3.html" class="language">C++</a>
    <a href="subpages/sub-page4.html" class="language">C#</a>
    <a href="subpages/sub-page5.html" class="language">Rust</a>
    <a href="subpages/sub-page6.html" class="language">Java</a>
    <a href="subpages/sub-page7.html" class="language">Python</a>
    <a href="subpages/sub-page8.html" class="language">Golang</a>
    <a href="subpages/sub-page9.html" class="language">PHP</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

i tried to adjust how much the list is moved up, but it either has changed height after the animation is finished, or jitters during the animation

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the only reason it moved up while expanding, was because i had "align-items: center" in the container, after removing it, i managed to make the animation work with a few lines of CSS, and no JavaScript.

```css
.languages-dropdown {
    padding: 17px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(53, 53, 53);
    height: 59px;
    width: 230px;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.languages-dropdown:hover {
    height: 370px;
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.language {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="languages-dropdown">
      <p class="title">Języki programowania</p>
      <br>
      <a href="subpages/sub-page0.html" class="language">Javascript</a>
      <a href="subpages/sub-page1.html" class="language">B</a>
      <a href="subpages/sub-page2.html" class="language">C</a>
      <a href="subpages/sub-page3.html" class="language">C++</a>
      <a href="subpages/sub-page4.html" class="language">C#</a>
      <a href="subpages/sub-page5.html" class="language">Rust</a>
      <a href="subpages/sub-page6.html" class="language">Java</a>
      <a href="subpages/sub-page7.html" class="language">Python</a>
      <a href="subpages/sub-page8.html" class="language">Golang</a>
      <a href="subpages/sub-page9.html" class="language">PHP</a
</div>
```